# Regular expression php for a pro

Tags: php, regex

Can you help me with a regular expression for this:

```
$value = '["number"]';
or
$value = '["number","number"]';
or
$value = '["number","number","number"]';
or
...
...
...
...
$value = '["number","number","number","number","number","number","number"......,"number"]';


//$number can be rand(0, 99.....999);
```

I need the result to be validated as true or false!

Comment: Do you need validation?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to match here, or that any of the code would function. /\["\d+"(,"\d+")*\]/ may work

Comment: $value = '["21","456"]'; =>true , $value = '["21a","456"]'; => false, $value = '['21'',"456"]'; =>false...

Comment: Are you trying to validate AND get the values?

Comment: @user2875157, what is your question?

Comment: I don`t know why you out this on hold because @Ilya Bursov understood exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version:

```
function test($v)
{
    if (preg_match('/^\\[("number")(,"number")*\\]$/', $v))
        echo 'ok<br>';
    else
        echo 'fail<br>';
}
```

or if "number" is really digits, this one:

```
function test($v)
{
    if (preg_match('/^\\[("[0-9]+")(,"[0-9]+")*\\]$/', $v))
        echo 'ok<br>';
    else
        echo 'fail<br>';
}
```

NOTE - only positive naturals are accepted, need to change to negative and decimal/floating numbers

Comment: worked like I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to use PCRE? Your example is valid json.

```
$array = json_decode('["number", "number", "123"]');
var_dump($array);
```

If you need numbers only, you can filter it.

```
$new_array = array_filter($array, 'ctype_digit');
$result = count($array) == $new_array? $new_array : null;

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: it will return Array ( [2] => 123 ) , so it`s not valid, it needs to return null or the array

Comment: @user2875157, update your question.

Comment: $number = '["3","3","32","456","45","3"]'; => true , $number = '["3","3","ss","2234","45","3"]'; => false . thanks

Comment: @user2875157 What are you talking about? If `var_dump()` is printing `Array ( [2] => 123 )` its because its an array. I don't see whats the problem.